# Which word means “bulky and slow-moving” when applied especially to bureaucracies?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there is a word that commonly occurs as a collocation with governmental systems that are slow, unwieldy, inefficient, even kind of obstructed, but I can’t remember it.

The idea is a system with a limited range of movement, like just to carry out some operation you can imagine is like a slow machine which first does one slow necessary action, then another, and so on, till it’s completed.

Words like bulky and cumbersome come to mind but aren’t it. I think it might have a “b” in it, but I wouldn’t want to lead someone astray in case I’m mistaken on that point.

It would be an adjective, to be used like “Their _____ welfare system means that people only receive benefits months after their first applying.”

Thank you.

Comment: Bureaucratic says it all. Starts with a B, continues with the speed and cheer of a sloth, and ends by tripping over itself with self-justification.

Answer (score 2):

> Their **lumbering** welfare system means that people only receive
> benefits months after their first applying.

**lumbering** (adj.)

> Moving in a slow, heavy, awkward way.
>
> *Like any other titanic, lumbering, inefficient machine, Hollywood
> studios dangerously pollute the atmosphere.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lumbering)

> Moving heavily, clumsily, or noisily [*Webster’s New World College
> Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lumbering)

---

> Conservatives have yet to challenge conclusively the contention that a
> government which devotes huge swathes of taxpayer cash to tackling
> 'social inequality' through a **lumbering welfare system** is more
> caring than one which believes  in empowering the individual. [Mark
> Field; *Between the Crashes*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Between_the_Crashes/Zf6tAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lumbering%20welfare%20system%22&pg=PT92&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> No, my dear Sir, let us all join hand and heart in overturning the old
> **lumbering system of education**, *let us deliver our children from this house of bondage*, this worse than Egyptian slavery, and say to
> them, be ye free, for ye are men like ourselves; ..." [Richard Hiley; *A
> Supposed Dialog...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Supposed_Dialogue_between_the_Shade_of/IN_JxtP3YVkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lumbering%20system%20of%22&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover) (1835)

> His reign name Yongzheng, meaning "Harmonious Justice," proclaimed the
> intended direction of his rule, and he brought prosperity to the
> nation and efficiency to the **lumbering governmental bureaucracy.**
> [L. Bosch and D. Mancoff; *Icons of Beauty: Art, Culture, and the
> Image of Women*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Icons_of_Beauty_Art_Culture_and_the_Imag/L5RxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lumbering%20governmental%22&pg=PA322&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

(**Lumbering** also has the *B* you imagined.)

Comment: It's been gaining traction for decades, and ***lumbering** bureaucracy* is currently [almost exactly as popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ponderous+bureaucracy%2Chidebound+bureaucracy%2Clumbering+bureaucracy&year_start=1930&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) as my ***ponderous** bureaucracy*. For my money though, ***lumbering*** more strongly implies *actually moving* (but *unstoppable*, and not easily "steered" / controlled). Whereas ***ponderous*** is more evocative of the inertia that almost prevents movement in the first place. Horses for courses.

Comment: (I hope you won't mind if I include this extra term in my chart. I think it's useful to see them side-by-side.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not at all! *Ponderous* lost much ground--clearly under its own weight :-)

Comment: Maybe something about the "zeitgeist" of the 60s (anti-establishment hippiedom, etc.) accounts for the meteoric rise of ***ponderous*** back then. But as an incorrigible ole fart myself, I'm quite prepared to believe it's just an example of English "dumbing down".  As more of the general population start using / encountering such relatively rarefied metaphors, the proportion of them who get confused by erroneous conflation with ***ponder=consider deeply*** rises. Not quite the same as the fall from grace of ***niggardly***, but maybe still a side-effect of dumbing down.

Comment: And don't forget _elephantine_.

Answer (score 1):

> [**ponderous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponderous) *- slow and awkward because of being very heavy or large*

[Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ponderous+bureaucracy%2Chidebound+bureaucracy%2Clumbering+bureaucracy&year_start=1930&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) a chart showing that ***ponderous*** is used of bureaucracies more often than ***hidebound*** *(unwilling or unable to change because of tradition or convention)*, but both are very common. Although superficially they look like significantly different metaphoric references, I'd say that in practice they both convey almost exactly the same concept.

[image]